# Would a star be observed to burn brighter traveling at relativistic speeds?

Tags: relativity

Would a star, similar to our own, be observed to "burn" differently at relativistic speeds?

I am only thinking this because the observed relativistic mass would change.

Comment: There is no such thing as relativistic mass; there is relativistic Doppler effect though.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/180698/520 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222809/520 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/520 Short-short version: you are the victim of bad (and decades abandoned) terminology.

Comment: @KyleKanos: in the same meaning as heavy protons in the LHC ? answer would be perhaps no because the star "burns" in its frame unless it collides with another one or it spins at a relativistic speed :)

Comment: finally, this question is similar to [Photons inside a box](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137316/photons-inside-a-box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The increased, "relativistic mass"* would *not* make the star burn brighter overall.  [Relativistic Beaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_beaming), however, would make the star appear brighter to viewers in its direction of motion, and dimmer to observers from whom it is moving away.

Additionally, because of time-dilation for the moving object, the star would actually appear *dimmer* to the (stationary) observer.  Because time for the star seems to be moving more slowly to the observer, the star would seem to live longer --- thus to conserve the total energy output, its luminosity would appear lower.

*This is, really, poor and outdated terminology.  'Mass' is just good-old, rest-mass, and the effects you are thinking about should be considered as effects to the momentum and/or energy.  See the comments by @KyleKanos and @dmckee.

Comment: What about an observer moving in a direction orthogonal to the direction observer-star?