# Why does the Yukawa potential fail for the strong force?

Tags: potential, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force, mesons, gluons

The [gluon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon) is a massless particle, so according to the [Yukawa potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential) the strong force should have a $r^{-1}$ potential. However, that is clearly not the case.

Is it because the gluons themselves can interact with each other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Questions about Yukawa Potential for Strong Force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/668573/)